# can you use variable limits of integration with the Cubature library

Tags: r, numerical-integration

I'm trying to use a variable limit of integration using the Cubature library.

For example:

```
adaptIntegrate(function(x) {x[1]*x[2]},
    lowerLimit = c(0,0),
    upperLimit = c(x[2],1))$integral
```

This doesn't work

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The integral has form `\int_O^1 \int_0^{x[2]} f dx[1] dx[2]`

The domain of integration is a triangle (make a picture!) with vertices (0,0), (0,1), (1,1). For such a domain, use the `SimplicialCubature` package.

```
> f <- function(x) x[1]*x[2]
> S <- cbind(c(0,0),c(0,1),c(1,1)) # the triangle (simplex)
> library(SimplicialCubature)
> adaptIntegrateSimplex(f, S)
$integral
[1] 0.125

$estAbsError
[1] 1.25e-13

$functionEvaluations
[1] 32
```

Answer (score 0):

Cubature is a package for adaptive multidimensional integration over hypercubes. I am also looking for packages which do multidimensional integration over any specific region (i.e. use variable as limits), anyone knows?

In addition, the definition of the function is not appropriate. I guess what you want is

```
function(x1,x2) x1*x2
```

Comment: Thank You, Now I know why variable limits don't work with Cubature.